# send the unicode value from Android to C# Webservice

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to send the Unicode value to WCF web service from Android app but I keep getting the string value as ????? in WCF web service. Below are the android code and C# code for web service.

```
                GTPostData gtPostData = new GTPostData(); //DTO Object
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                String post = "イメージお願いし";

                gtPostData.setPortalId(portalId);
                gtPostData.setPost(post);
                gtPostData.setProjectId(data.getProjectId());
                gtPostData.setQuestionId(data.getQuestionId());
                gtPostData.setUserId(panelistId);

                GTPostDataRequest request = new GTPostDataRequest();
                request.setGtPostData(gtPostData);//creating the request object

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(request)); 

                String webServiceUrl= ResourcePicker.getServiceURL(session.getPortal(),session.getPortalId(),true);
                String addGtPostMethod = ResourcePicker.getString(portal, "add_gt_post");

                AsyncPostRequest asyncRequest = new AsyncPostRequest();
                asyncRequest.setServiceMethod(addGtPostMethod);
                asyncRequest.setServiceUrl(webServiceUrl);
                asyncRequest.setPostObject(jsonObject);//set object for post call
                SendGtPostAsyncService asyncService = new SendGtPostAsyncService(asyncRequest, context, session, db, data.getPostId());
                asyncService.execute();//call the async task
```

---

WCF web service call (C#)

```
public bool AddGTPost(GTPostData GtPostData)
        {
            bool isAdded = false;
            try
            {
                sci.Debug(frendlyName, screenName, "", "Enter AddGTPost ->> " + GtPostData);//These are trace methods which will print the results in txt file.


                sci.Debug(frendlyName, screenName, "", "Enter AddGTPost - Unicode Post ->> " + GtPostData.post);//These are trace methods which will print the results in txt file. Here I'm getting results as "??????"
```

So please some one help me what is my mistake here?

Comment: there's some problem with string encoding for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For your webservice I hope you are not missing UTF-16 format 
also in the configuration you are using :

```
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);
    GlobalizationSection configSection = (GlobalizationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/globalization");            
    configSection.RequestEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    configSection.ResponseEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not working for me. Can you please explain more that where should I need to add this configuration?